# Bluetooth connceted speakers - volume not adjusting

Tags: bluetooth, sound

When I connect to my speakers via bluethooth (listening to music through them) and adjust the volume on my laptop, it adjust the volume for the internal laptop speakers and not the bluetooth connected ones. Then I manually go to settings and select the bluetooth connected speakers and only then does it adjust the vlolume fro them. 
Is there a way to make elementary os automatically recognize when they are connected so I can adjust the volume immediately without having to go to settings every time?

Thanks.

Comment: I just get open audio settings every time. It's not ideal, but it's better than not having control over volume.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an older post regarding this situation for Ubuntu 15.04 and a bug report that was filed for it. That can be found here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-sound/+bug/1404729

I tried to duplicate your issue using a set of Bluetooth headphones but was unable to do so and do not have a wireless speaker to try out but I think the resolution put forth in the bug report would be worth a try and can always be undone easily. It involves adding some lines to a Pulse Audio file using a text editor.

You can open a Terminal window and type:

```
sudo scratch-text-editor /etc/pulse/default.pa
```

Once the file is open in Scratch, add the following two lines to the bottom of the file:

```
# automatically switch to newly-connected devices
load-module module-switch-on-connect
```

Once you've added the two lines, close Scratch to save the file. I would then reboot, connect the Bluetooth speaker, then test the volume to see if you've got it solved. I would also disconnect the Bluetooth speaker and verify you're able to adjust the volume on the internal speaker(s).

Good Luck and please reply back as to whether or not this was successful.

Comment: Awesome Lri!!! Glad you were able to get it solved!!!

Comment: such a great community! :) no company, no matter how refined their products are can ever replace a good community.. I hope many users will find your solution helpful as did I!